# Deleting from firebase onclick

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a basic CRUD app and I am using Firebase for my backend. I have implemented the create and read functionality, but I am having problems with the delete method. The results are shown from my database in a html table and after each result there is a delete button, however when you click on the delete button, firebase gives me this error: `Uncaught Error: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: null`

Why, what am I doing wrong?

here is my js:

```
const animalList = document.querySelector('#animal-list');
const form = document.querySelector('#add-animals');

function renderAnimals(doc) {
let tr = document.createElement('tr');
let td = document.createElement('td');
let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
let editButton = document.createElement('button')
// Animal properties
let name = document.createElement('div');
let species = document.createElement('div');
let age = document.createElement('div');
let last_fed = document.createElement('div');
let last_shed = document.createElement('div');
let diet = document.createElement('div');
let basking_area_temp = document.createElement('div');
let cold_part_temp = document.createElement('div');
let humidity = document.createElement('div');
let additional_info = document.createElement('div');
// Edit Form inputs and buttons
let editForm = document.createElement('form');
let submit = document.createElement('input'); 
let nameInput = document.createElement('input');
let speciesInput = document.createElement('input');
let ageSpecies = document.createElement('input');
let lastFedInput = document.createElement('input');
let lastShedInput = document.createElement('input');
let dietInput = document.createElement('input');
let baskingAreaTempInput = document.createElement('input');
let coldPartTempInput = document.createElement('input');
let humidityInput = document.createElement('input');
let additionalInfoInput = document.createElement('input');
// Edit modal creation
let modal = document.createElement('div');
let modalDialog = document.createElement('div');
let modalContent = document.createElement('div');
let span = document.createElement('span');
let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
let nameLabel = document.createElement('label');
let speciesLabel = document.createElement('label');
let ageLabel = document.createElement('label');
let lastFedLabel = document.createElement('label');
let lastShedLabel = document.createElement('label');
let dietLabel = document.createElement('label');
let baskingAreaTempLabel = document.createElement('label');
let coldPartTempLabel = document.createElement('label');
let humidityLabel = document.createElement('label');
let additionalInfoLabel = document.createElement('label');

// Class and data setting
tr.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
name.textContent = `name: ${doc.data().name}`;
deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
deleteButton.setAttribute('class','btn btn-danger');
editButton.textContent = 'Edit';
editButton.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-info');
editForm.setAttribute('class', 'form-group');
modal.setAttribute('id','editModal');
modal.setAttribute('class','modal ');
modal.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
modalDialog.setAttribute('class', 'modal-dialog');
modalContent.setAttribute('class','modal-content container');
span.textContent = 'X';
span.setAttribute('class','close');
h2.textContent = 'Edit Animal';
speciesLabel.innerHTML = 'Species:';
nameLabel.innerHTML = 'Name:';
ageLabel.textContent = 'Age:';
lastFedLabel.textContent='Last Fed:';
lastShedLabel.textContent= 'Last Shed:';
dietLabel.textContent = 'Diet:';
baskingAreaTempLabel.textContent = 'Basking temps';
coldPartTempLabel.textContent = 'Cold Part Temps';
humidityLabel.textContent = 'Humidity';
additionalInfoInput.textContent = 'Additional Info';
species.textContent = `species: ${doc.data().species}`;
age.textContent = `age: ${doc.data().age}`;
last_fed.textContent = `last fed: ${doc.data().last_fed}`;
last_shed.textContent = `last shed: ${doc.data().last_shed}`;
diet.textContent = `diet: ${doc.data().diet}`;
basking_area_temp.textContent =`basking area temp: ${ doc.data().basking_area_temp}`;
cold_part_temp.textContent =  `cold part temp: ${doc.data().cold_part_temp}`;
humidity.textContent = `humidity: ${doc.data().humidity}`;
additional_info.textContent = `additional info: ${doc.data().additional_info}`;
editForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
editForm.setAttribute('action',"#");
editForm.setAttribute('class','edit-form');
submit.setAttribute('type',"submit");
submit.setAttribute('value',"Update");
submit.setAttribute('class',"btn btn-success");
nameLabel.setAttribute('for','name');
speciesLabel.setAttribute('for','name');
ageLabel.setAttribute('for','name');
lastFedLabel.setAttribute('for','');
lastShedLabel.setAttribute('for','last shed');
dietLabel.setAttribute('for','diet');
nameInput.setAttribute('class','form-control')
speciesInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
ageSpecies.setAttribute('class','form-control');
lastFedInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
lastShedInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
baskingAreaTempInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
coldPartTempInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
humidityInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
additionalInfoInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
speciesInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');
dietInput.setAttribute('class','form-control');

//Visualizing the table
td.appendChild(species);
td.append(age);
td.append(last_fed);
td.append(last_shed);
td.append(diet);
td.append(basking_area_temp);
td.append(cold_part_temp);
td.append(humidity);
td.append(additional_info);
td.append(deleteButton);
td.append(editButton);
td.appendChild(nameInput);
td.append(ageSpecies);
td.append(lastFedInput);
td.append(lastShedInput);
td.append(dietInput);
td.append(baskingAreaTempInput);
td.append(coldPartTempInput);
td.append(humidityInput);
// td.append(additionalInfoInput);
td.append(speciesInput);
tr.appendChild(td);
editForm.append(nameLabel);
editForm.appendChild(nameInput);
editForm.append(ageLabel);
editForm.append(ageSpecies);
editForm.append(lastFedLabel);
editForm.append(lastFedInput);
editForm.append(lastShedLabel);
editForm.append(lastShedInput);
editForm.append(dietLabel);
editForm.append(dietInput);
editForm.append(baskingAreaTempLabel);
editForm.append(baskingAreaTempInput);
editForm.append(coldPartTempLabel);
editForm.append(coldPartTempInput);
editForm.append(humidityLabel);
editForm.append(humidityInput);
editForm.append(additionalInfoLabel);
// editForm.append(additionalInfoInput);
editForm.append(speciesLabel);
editForm.append(speciesInput);
editForm.append(submit);
td.append(editForm);
tr.appendChild(td);
modal.append(modalDialog);
modalDialog.append(modalContent);
modalContent.append(span);
modalContent.append(h2);
td.append(modal);
modalContent.append(editForm);
animalList.appendChild(tr);

// Firebase operations

//deleting data
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    db.collection('animals').doc(id).delete();
})

editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = 'flex';
})

span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
})
}

// getting data from the back end
db.collection('animals').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
        if(change.type == 'added') {
            renderAnimals(change.doc);
        } else if (change.type == 'removed') {
            let li = animalList.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id + ']');
            animalList.removeChild(li);
        }
    })
})

// adding data
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    db.collection('animals').add({
        species: form.species.value,
        name: form.name.value,
        age: form.age.value,
        last_fed: document.querySelector('#last-fed').value,
        last_shed: document.querySelector('#last-shed').value,
        diet: form.diet.value,
        basking_area_temp: document.querySelector('#basking-area-temperature').value,
        cold_part_temp: document.querySelector('#cold-temperature').value,
        humidity: form.humidity.value,
        additional_info: document.querySelector('#additional-info').value

    })
})
```

and my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Repti Care</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <h2>Add a new Animal</h2>
    <form class="form-group" id="add-animals">
    Species: <input type="text" id="species" class="form-control">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" >
    Age: <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control">
    Last Fed: <input type="date" id="last-fed" class="form-control">
    Last Shed: <input type="date" id="last-shed" class="form-control">
    Diet: <input type="text" id="diet" class="form-control">
    Basking area temperature: <input type="text" id="basking-area-temperature" class="form-control">
    Cold part temperature: <input type="text" id="cold-temperature" class="form-control">
    Humidity: <input type="text" id="humidity" class="form-control">
    Addition Info: <textarea class="form-control" id="additional-info"></textarea>
    <button id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
    <h3>View Current Animals</h3>
    <table id="animal-list">
     <th>Animals</th>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBSuC8nqJzLe7d5jKS-_nE15kaI9Y6NIfI",
    authDomain: "repti-care-32176.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://repti-care-32176.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "repti-care-32176",
    storageBucket: "repti-care-32176.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "632910932105"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
</script>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried looking up the error and reading firebase documentation but I could not find anything.

Comment: Most won't even read your question if they see this wall of code, please try to include only relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you attempt to set the `data-id` property on a `<tr>` element, but try to read it from a `<td>` element inside that `<tr>`. See:

```
tr.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
...
td.append(deleteButton);
...
tr.appendChild(td);
...
let id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
```

So the parent will not be your `tr` but the directly enclosing `td`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you passed an invalid value to the `doc()` method here:

```
db.collection('animals').doc(id).delete();
```

You need to debug your code and figure out why `id` is null or undefined.